# How can I tell which database a particular website updates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webserver

I'm backing up data from a website made with ruby on rails. There are at least 3 installations of rails on the machine, and as far as I know only one of them is serving a particular website. **How can I determine which of these installations of rails is serving a that website, and which database it is using?**

Comment: disable an install, test site, repeat until the site stops working?

Comment: @Marc: I don't know if I can safely disable the site.

Comment: Your title doesn't match the content of the question. Do you wan to know the installation of Rails or the database?

Comment: @Simone Carletti: I'm under the impression that the website is using a database in the `db` directory, but in the end I want to find the database, not the installation.

Answer (score 1):

Look in each app's `config/database.yml`. The database it uses will be listed under the `production` key.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find out which database is being used and you are able to make a ssh connection -- inspect the database configuration used in the environment. This method is shows you the final connection config taking environment variables into account. I'm assuming production in this example.

`$ bundle exec rails console production`

`> ActiveRecord::Base.connection`

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is to determine which webserver (typically nginx or apache) is serving the application, and to determine which version is running via its configuration.

```
ps aux
```

can show you which webserver process is running.  If the box isn't running nginx or apache, it's instead running some Ruby app server on port 80.  If so, *that's* the directory you want.

After you've located the web server, find its configuration directory and use grep for the domain name.  Some examples might include /etc/httpd, /var/www, /etc/nginx, etc.

```
grep -r yourdomain.com /etc/httpd
```

If you don't find anything with this search, it may be the default site for the web server.  In this case, replace yourdomain.com with "Rails" or "Proxy" for further hints.

This should help you track down which directory is serving the app.  The config/database.yml in that directory usually has the database information.